# Delete Row in Google Sheets Based on Cell Text (if contains)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will automatically delete the row if the cell contains, but does not exactly match, the condition. For example, the script would delete the rows if the cell contains gmail.com, as part of a larger email

```
123@gmail.com
123@yahoo.com
456@gmail.com
456@yahoo.com
```

The two yahoo emails would be saved because they do not meet the condition. However, I am unsure of the proper conditional dictation to use when writing my script. Here is what I have so far.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var r = s.getRange('B:B');
  var v = r.getValues();
  for(var i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    if(v[0,i] 'gmail.com')
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
};
```

I would put a ==, but this will only delete rows that match exactly with gmail.com. What would I use in place of the == to make it essentially a text contains condition?

Comment: In your script, ``v`` is 2 dimensional array. In the case whether the value includes ``gmail.com``, how about using [``indexOf()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)? So how about modifying from ``if(v[0,i] 'gmail.com')`` to ``if (v[i][0].indexOf('gmail.com') > -1)``?

Comment: if you don't use Excel, please don't tag with Excel. There are many differences between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deleteMatchingRows(string) {
  var string=string||'gmail.com';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lngth=sh.getLastRow();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,2,lngth,1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var n=0;  
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(vA[i][0] && vA[i][0].indexOf(string)>-1){
      sh.deleteRow(i-n+1);
      n++;
    }    
  }
}
```